# Make 2 players with iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I made a page that allow 2 players to play game, I use 2 iframes to load 2 file .html of game, first iframe for player 1, second iframe for player 2.

But i have a problem that I want to play as player 2 I have to click on the iframe 2, and same with player 1; that mean I can only play one player at a time.

So you guys have any ideas about this? Is there any way to play 2 iframes at once? (I have set up different button for each player)

Here is the screen which i described above

[image]

Comment: inserted picture + removed unwanted words + added html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function "parent".

Example are as below:

define:

main page: **demo.html**

sub page: **a.html**  & **b.html**

**demo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe id="frame_A" src="a.html"></iframe>
        <iframe id="frame_B" src="b.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function callBFun() {
                parent['frame_B'].changeHiValue(document.getElementById('user').value);
            }
            
            function callDirect() {
                parent['frame_B'].document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML =
                    'Control：====>' + document.getElementById('user').value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 style="color: red;">This is a.html</h1>
        <input type="text" id="user" size="8"><input type="button" onclick="callBFun()" value="call function from b.html"><input type="button" onclick="callDirect()" value="call dom from b.html">
    </body>
</html>
```

#### b.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeHiValue(value) {
      document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML = 'By calling：==>>==>>' + value;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="color: blue;">It's the b</h1>
  The value from a.html：
  <label id="hi" style="color: red;"></label>
</body>

</html>
```

Good luck;